# How do I create a countdown timer like in Google SantaTracker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I do know how to make a countdown timer in javascript, but how do I achieve the **flipping effect** as in [Google SantaTracker's website](http://google.com/santatracker/)...??

Comment: Google "jquery countdown timer" and you'll find many of them, and some look like this.

Comment: yes.... that one is infact javascript.

Comment: @Barmar: I did find some in Codecanyon. But they're all paid plugins. I can't see the actual code in there...

Comment: What's stopping you from cracking open the inspector and taking a look, I did and I can see some pretty funky code flying around

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here. I modified Chris Nanney's [flip counter](http://cnanney.com/journal/code/apple-style-counter-revisited/) a while back to allow for count downs. Feel free to use.

https://bitbucket.org/fresheyeball/apple-style-flip-counter-with-leading-zeros/overview

Comment: Thanks a ton! Just what I wanted! with detailed explanation. :D